# Change background of all buttons on click

Tags: java, android, xml, button

Okay so I'm trying to stylize this tictactoe game I'm working on for a project. When I press new game, I would like some sort of an array that would change the background of each Button to a color. Then when the user clicks a button to make their move there, that space will change to a different color depending on the player (I have a PlayerTurn flag variable that determines this). I would also like to a value in an int array according to an index that corresponds with that button. How can I assign each button a numerical value that I can later use to index into my array?

Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
    Button buttons[] = new Button[9];
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ArrayList` of the type `Button`:

```
private ArrayList<Button> mList;

onCreate()//
mList = new ArrayList<>();
mList.add(yourButton);
.....................

for(int i = 0 ; i< mList.size(); i++)
  mList.get(i).setBackground(//your color);
```

Comment: Okay, so how can I then make sure that when I click, say the center button, only that button changes color.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the code I'm using. I'm not familiar with Arraylist or how they differ from Arrays.

Comment: you need to use OnClickListener for each item

Comment: Would something like this work:

buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: Yes but you still need to use OnClick method for each button